# How to find set difference in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

What is the **'except'** equivalent command in **mysql**?

```
SELECT name FROM table1 except SELECT name FROM table2
```

Comment: phpmyadmin is just a tool to access and operate on mysql database. You have to look for the right command on that SQL dialect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by *@Lelio Faieta*: Phpmyadmin is just a tool to access and operate on mysql database.

But if you want to achieve the "except" concept try like this:

```
SELECT name FROM table1 where name NOT IN( SELECT name FROM table2)
```

This will give you names in `table1` that are not in `table2`.

Answer (score 0):

Often easiest to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN, and then in the WHERE clause check that there is no matching field.

```
SELECT name 
FROM table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.name = table2.name
WHERE table2.name IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will work for your scenario:

```
select A.* 
from
(SELECT name FROM table1) A,
((SELECT name FROM table1) B
where
A.name != B.name;
```